# dc.js pie chart drawPaths is not a function

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to add some labels on a DC.js pie chart, like:
http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/pie-external-labels.html
However, when I did the same thing as in the source code, I got the error message from console: drawPaths is not a function. Actually, externalLabels and externalRadiusPadding also doesn't work in my code. Anybody knows what's going on with my code? Thank you in advance.

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-month");
 chart
        .width(384)
        .height(240)
        .innerRadius(50)
        //.externalLabels(10)
        //.externalRadiusPadding(50)
        //.drawPaths(true)
        .dimension(monthDim)
        .group(month_total)
        .label(function (d) {
            return dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2 * Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
        })
        .legend(dc.legend());
```

Comment: Missed this due to wrong tag (fixed). You probably need to get the 2.0 beta for this feature.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thank you very much. Sorry I am new to DC.js.Could you give me more info about 2.0 beta or any references? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, if you're using the CDN, just [select one of the betas](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/dc/2.0.0-beta.32). Or if you're using npm, then depend on `"dc": "~2.0.0-beta"`. It doesn't come up as the default but I'd like to encourage everyone to move to 2.0 because it will be released soon. It's also [documented on the master branch](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md).

Comment: @Gordon Thank you so much! This's great point let try this.